# Creating web form using code

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, webforms

I am using visual studio 2010 asp.net. I am creating a website for people to upload tabs for guitar. once they upload, the admin approves it, and then I have my problem. I don't want to manually create a web form for each tab page. I want that once the admin approves the tabs, that it will automatically create a web form with only few specific variables which will be different from page to page. Is it possible?
Thanks in advance, Eitan.

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: You can somewhat do this... you can bind types to input types. Then you just loop through each property and dump the input type. You'll need to standardise your naming conventions and what not. You can either take a code approach to creating the inputs, or use partial views for each input. You should sit down and pen out what you actually want, because otherwise you'll add so much unneeded code. Look into Razor.